# Rename Angular2 import module

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I wanted to rename the @angular module to angular2, since I find it better readable and wanted to understand how imports work.

So before my attempt to change this, the `systemjs.config.js` looked like this:

```
(function(global)
{
    var map =
    {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        /*...*/
    };

    var packages =
    {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        /*...*/
    };

    var config =
    {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    if (global.filterSystemConfig)
    {
        global.filterSystemConfig(config);
    }

    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

And the imports in app-Typescript-files looked like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

This works as expected. Now I changed the `systemjs.config.js` to this:

```
(function(global)
{
    var map =
    {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        'angular2': 'node_modules/@angular',
        /*...*/
    };

    var packages =
    {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2/common', { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        /*...*/
    };

    var config =
    {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    if (global.filterSystemConfig)
    {
        global.filterSystemConfig(config);
    }

    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

So that I could import Angular2 modules like this:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
```

When I try to run `npm start`, I get the following errow now:

> file-where-i-import.component.ts(1,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.

Why does it not work like that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the SystemJS configuration is only for runtime.

TypeScript compilation relies on `d.ts` files for modules, types, ... and on this configuration. The compiler will look into the `@angular` folder under `node_modules` for this to resolve modules so module names for Angular2 will necessary start with the `@angular/` prefix.

Comment: So it is not possible for me to make it work anyway?

Comment: I think that it could work at runtime but you'll have compilation errors... That said, it's not only a module renaming because some new public modules are now present in rc versions whereas you only have `angular2/core`, `angular2/common` in beta versions.

Comment: All right, thanks for your help. I think I will just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have so much problem with @angular dont use it.. Kidding..
you may try below,

create a new file with name angular2 with below,

```
export * from "@angular/core";
```

and when you refer you may use

```
import { Component } from 'path to angular2 module';
```

Now it is not exactly what you might want because you have to use reference path rather than module name. Also you have to include all the modules from angular you might want to use. You may also filter and expose only what you may want to by using names of export like Component etc, also you have opportunity to add your modules along with angular one's.

If you want to know more about How Module resolution works in Typescript you may look at [Typescript Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

**Update :**
you may have a folder structure like below (excerpts from [Typescript Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)),

```
   /root/src/angular2/package.json (if it specifies a "typings" property)
   /root/src/angular2/index.ts
   /root/src/angular2/index.d.ts
```

then you may use

```
   import { Component } from 'angular2';
```

Comment: Interesting attempt, but I think that importing everything might slow down the app for not much benefit. Thanks for your help, it's always good to know some alternatives. And I actually don't have a problem with it, I was just changing some stuff in systemjs.config and thought that maybe it could work to just rename something. Out of interest I tried and failed, and was wondering why :D

Comment: Not sure if it will slow down, but read about this on Angular Docs [Barrel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#B).. A barrel is a way to rollup exports from several modules into a single convenience module. The barrel itself is a module file that re-exports selected exports of other modules. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a [path mapping](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039#pathMapping) for this in *tsconfig.json*:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    // ...omitted other options...
    "baseUrl": "",
    "paths": {
        "angular2/*": [
            "node_modules/@angular/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

This feature is coming in TypeScript 2.0, but you can use it today: `npm install typescript@next`

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a build-in way, and if I am just missing something. But thank you anyway for your help :)

Comment: @ChristianDreher there is. This is the built in way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a built-in way with the current version I am using

Comment: I gave your solution another shot, but it does not work with node 6.1.0 and npm 3.8.6, since typescript@next only upgrades typescript to 1.9. So `paths` is still missing. I hope it will be available soon, since your solution is by far the best apart from the fact that it is not appliciable at the moment (will change accepted answer as soon as your solution works)